# How to remove the over x line in pylab (python)?

Tags: python, histogram

how to remove the over line after banana so that the histogram can stick to the vertical line?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Svg')
from pylab import*

label = ['apple','orange', 'banana']
number = [5,4,3]

barwidth =0.5

bar_location= range(len(number))

bar(bar_location,number,width=barwidth)
xlim(0-barwidth,len(number))
xticks([ i + barwidth/2 for i in bar_location], label)
tittle('fruits')
xlabel('my_fruit')
ylabel('number')
savefig('fruits.svg')
show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the range of the x-axis with *xlim()*, e.g.:

```
xlim(0 - barwidth, len(number) - 0.5)
```

(but make sure to insert it before *savfig()*).

Comment: So is it (-0.5,0-barwidth,len(number),2.5) @Christian Geiger

Comment: sorry, looks like I didn't read your post carefully enough, I guess what you are looking for is *xlim(0-barwidth,len(number)-0.5)*